# Error synchronizing values in React. Component useEffect get executed before costume hook

Tags: reactjs

I have this component that shows an alert if some condition is met from values of my  custom hook.

The problem that I have is the alert is executed several times because at Home first render `value1` and `value2` are false but then, `value1` and `value2` change because the useEffect from the `useCustomHook` is executed, making the Home useEffect get executed again.

If I remove `value1` and `value2` from Home useEffect array dependencies, when Home first render, `value1` and `value2` are false and therefor the alert never executes.

How can I solve this?

My component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import useCustomHook from './useCustomHook';

function Home() {
  const { value1, value2 } = useCustomHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value1 && !value2) {
      alert('Alert: value1 is truthy and value2 is falsy');
    }
  }, [value1, value2]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      <p>Value 1: {value1 ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
      <p>Value 2: {value2 ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

And then my custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useCustomHook() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(false);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulating asynchronous operations
    setTimeout(() => {
      setValue1(true);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulating asynchronous operations
    setTimeout(() => {
      setValue2(true);
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  return { value1, value2 };
}

export default useCustomHook;
```

In this example, I don't want the alert to execute because value1 and value2 are true but it currently does because it takes time to set value1 and value2 to true.

Comment: I was thinking at first if it's the soft warning from `StrictMode`, but then it seem like you have 3 `useEffect`s inside your custom Hooks all calling some asynchronous function that takes some time to execute. Until u provide reproducible code, logically to me, because you have 3 different Async FNs seems like it will be better if you can combine their logic into a single Effect .. at least for the `value2` as of right now perhaps what happens is its value changes from `false` (*initial*) -> `true` -> `false`. So, if it's not what you want then you want to `await` for all the logic at once.

Comment: Say in your 2nd `useEffect` you have dependency `value1` which is not really necessary, instead you can move its logic from the 3rd `useEffect` inside the 2nd, now in there you call `check()` which is an `async` FN that assigns `let scopedValue1 = await someFunctionThatTakesTime()` then check `if (scopedValue1){handle()}`. You see where I'm going with this?

Comment: Also now you wouldn't call `setValue1(!!(await someFunctionThatTakesTime()))` inside that `check` FN instead, you can now pass it to the `handle` as an argument, something like `if (scopedValue1){handle(scopedValue1)}` -> then `const handle = async (param1) => {
      const level = await someOtherFunc();
      setValue2(level);
      setValue1(param1);
    };`

Comment: @Aleksandar I updated the code to a workable example that exemplifies my problem.

Comment: your updated code as-is runs `alert` only once in this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-spence-w22ghd?file=/src/useCustomHook.js) while your *Effect* runs twice indeed. Now your code differs from your pre-edit version, so if you uncomment the 3rd `useEffect` that I wrote - it is the issue your described at which point my comments above solve it by tunneling all the `async` functions into 1 final value and only *then* update the state.

Comment: Maybe I should move this into an answer because it got quite lengthy, but your logic being you have both `value1` and `value2` as dependencies, it means you need both of their values to run `alert` and if they keep changing - then, whenever they *match your condition* is when `alert` will re-run.